# Node js require()[env] undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Brand new to node trying to understand a project. The project loads on dev on a windows machine just fine, but throws this error on Azure App Services..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
```

when trying:
`config.database` for example in `index.js`

**models/index.js**

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json'))[env];
>>> var whatever = config.database; <<<
```

**config/config.json**

```
{
  "development": {
    "logging": false, 
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "username": "whatever",
    "password": "whatever",
    "database": "whatever",
    "host": "whatever",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "encrypt": true
    }
  }
}
```

No idea where to start with this since it works fine on local. The file location seems correct, `path` is valid, `path.join()` works fine...

Thank you!

Comment: Is the value of `env` being set to `development`? Or is there something else in `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: Yep, I think that Azure is setting `NODE_ENV` to `production`.

Comment: I duplicated the development set in `config.json` and renamed to "production" so will see if that does it. Deploying now...

Comment: You shouldn't need to path.join() to get to something like a config.json.  just require('../config/config.json').  If you do need to use path.join, then make sure you get that ready first; const path = require('path');

Comment: @jfriend00 require() handles the differences between platforms for you, you can separate path components in require() using '/' on any platform.  But, you do need to require('path') before you can use it.  https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: @JeffBreadner - That wasn't really my point.  Your comment has absolutely nothing to do with this issue.  You make it sound like it's a potential problem.  The `require()` statement here has to be working or there would be an error on that line, but the error is not on that line, it's on the next line because `config` is `undefined` because `require(...)[env]` is `undefined`.  `require(...)` is not `undefined` here or there would have been an error on an earlier line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really only one main possibility here and you need to do a little bit of your own debugging to verify it.

Because this statement does not generate an error:

```
const config = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json'))[env];
```

That means that `require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json'))` is returning a Javascript object.  So, there must indeed be a file at the path you construct and it must be giving you an object when you `require()` it.

But, the error itself: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined` when you try to reference `config.database` means that `config` is `undefined`.  The only way that happens is that you're using a value for `env` that is not in your config object.

That's like trying to do this:

```
const obj = {development: {someKey: "someValue"}};  // what require() gives you
const env = "test";                                 // your value for env
const config = obj[env];                            // reading non-existent [env] property
console.log(config);                                // undefined
```

So, add `console.log(env)` to your code to see what `env` actually is and then verify that you have an object in your config data structure for that specific value (or set the desired value in the environment).

If you had verified the value of `env` yourself with basic debugging steps before posting here, you probably would have solved your own problem (hoping you can learn simple techniques to solve more of your own problems).

If you didn't follow all of my original logic, you could also just debug it like this:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
console.log("env: ", env);

const configPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json');
console.log("configPath: ", configPath);

const configObj = require(configPath);
console.log("configObj: ", configObj);

const config = configObj[env];
console.log("config: ", config);
```